# How to keep your hibernate levell 1 cache consistent through external updates?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching, orm

Please excuse me this question, but I can't find any solution through my research so far. (At least nothing that helped me)

**My Situation:**

- I am using hibernate for a vaadin webservice
- The webservice is taking uploaded documents and puts them unchanged via hibernate in my MySQL database
- A compute service in the background (a seperate process that later might be on another server) does computation tasks on the uploaded documents and adds the results again in the database
- The webservice recognizes the analysis results in the database and shows them to the user

**My Problem:**

- My problem is the level 1 hibernate cache
- After the compute service has been started he doesn't compute anything on later updated documents, since they don't appear in his cache when he fulfills the given search-query.
- My webservice overwrites made changes in the compute server, since it doesn't know anything about it as well.

I know that the hibernate level 1 cache is responsible for this behavior (lvl 2 cache is not active by the way).

**What I have tried so far**

- I've read a lot and tried several things, for example calling session.clear() on various places. This often gave me "session is closed" exceptions and didn't help me (although I read about people mentioning that this helped with their problems)
- I tried to make sure that the session is closed always in the end, but this didn't solve the problem, as well as I read that I dont need to close the sessions manually anyways, after I used transaction.commit() (I heard this is the standard in the session per request pattern)
- I tried closing my sessionfactory and reopening it every time my compute service needs to search the database. This works partially and probably full if I also do this on my web service, but this doesn't seem to be a very good solution to me (also memory consuming, not?)
- I tried adding

> < property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2< / property>

to my hibernate.cfg.xml, but this also worked only partially. Using this my compute service did computation tasks, but his changes got again overwritten everytime new data gets uploaded through the web service. So new uploads have been detected, but once a new upload has been arrived, all already analyzed documents get analyzed again.

- I read about a Query method called "setForceCacheRefresh(boolean forceCacheRefresh)" (e.g. from here http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/Query.html#setForceCacheRefresh%28boolean%29), but somehow I cant find this method in my hibernate version. Sad though, the description sounded good

I was always thinking about if the way I manage sessions is incorrect. My class DAO has two methods, which get called at every beginning and every end of a transaction.

```
public abstract class DAO {

/**
 * Returns the current hibernate session. Also takes care that there's
 * always an open hibernate transaction when needed.
 * 
 * @return Current hibernate session
 */
public static Session getSession() {
    Session currentSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession();
    if (!currentSession.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        currentSession.beginTransaction();
    }

    return currentSession;
}

/**
 * Closes the current hibernate session, if there is one.
 */
public static void closeSession() {
    Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    if (sess.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        sess.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    ThreadLocalSessionContext.unbind(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory());
}

}
```

I have also read something about Optimistic Locking with hibernate, but I'm not sure if this will solve my problem here. I read that Optimistic Locking will only throw an exception if the cache object isn't the one in the database. But does it also load (refresh) the cache then?

How did you handle this problem in your hibernate? Do you have any suggestions what I could do or did I even do something wrong in my DAO-class? I'm also happy about code examples. Again: I want that every process knows about changes made in the database by the other one. (I'd even disable the first cache, if I could, but since this isn't possible)

**Thanks a lot for every answer and thought you're sharing with me**

Comment: org.hibernate.CacheMode#REFRESH is the more general approach to refreshing cached values.  But it only effects second level caching (as did setForceCacheRefresh method btw).  Are your using a second level cache?  If not, sounds much more like you have a problem with running your sessions too long (stale data).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As mentioned in my title and in the post I'm only talking about the first level cache. The second level cache is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed my problem.

The first part could get fixed with the great help of Gergely Szilagyi and his answer:

> Attached object instances live only within a Session in Hibernate. If
>   you terminate your transactions and sessions correctly, the level 1
>   cache will be purged. What pattern do you use for session management?
>   Session-in-view?
>
> I'm asking this, because your problem seems to me like a
>   Session-termination issue.
>
> EDIT:
>
> I don't see Session.close() or at least Session.disconnect() in your
>   code. As far as I know it's not automatic with unbind().

(Thanks for this great post, if I could mark several answers as correct I would also mark yours!)

His answer let me think about my session-management and some of my problems got fixed through this.

The **second** part of my problem and also really important in my main question was how it is possible to **refresh** the first level cache/make it consistent. After a lot of research I found out that the hibernate Session class contains a method in which you can directly load an object from the database.

Given an Entity object entitiy that you want to refresh, you act as following:

```
//Call session.evict if this object is currently in the session, otherwise not necessary
//It deletes the object from the session cache (If you don't call this method although this object is currenlty in the session an exception will be thrown
session.evict(entity);
//session.get acccesses the database directly and returns you the actual saved entity
Ent1 updatedEntitEnty = (Ent1) session.get(Ent1.class, entity.getPrimaryUniqueID());
```

Now you can continue working with the received updated entity.

session.get(...) is here the most important method, since it accesses the database directly and ignores the cache. The given back object is the most up to date that is saved in the database.

**Take care: There is also a session.load(...) Method, which will not help in this case. load(..) accesses the cache and retrieves the object from there while get(..) does the right.**

**So if you want to retrieve the object from the database, don't use session.load(...)!**

I hope this answer helps others on one day, contact me if you have any questions.

Comment: You are absolutely incorrect wrt load/get.  Both will look into both levels of cache.  load() simply allows return of uninitialized proxies, whereas get() does not.  That is the only difference between them.

Comment: Well, I've found several sides (e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/ ), where it's stated that get would directly access the database. I did some small tests with inserting some values via hibernate, changing them manipulative in the background by hand and then re-reading the object with get and it worked fine for me. For me this seems like the value is directly read out from the database (which was my problem before). Anyway, since this allowed me to read out the current state it fixed my problem and so I can accept this as my answer.

Comment: Well, I've found several websites that claim the end of the world is near.. ;)  BUt I assure you both get and load look into both levels of cache.  You have to keep in mind that these answers are here for posterity as well, and I do not want the next person getting the wrong idea.

Comment: As I've said: It's working for me in my tests as well as in my application. It allows me to update the objects that are being hold in my cache (and also allows me to detect external updates) and was what I've been looking for. So why don't you provide some tests to specify your oppinion?

Comment: As the lead developer of Hibernate I have an entire slew of such tests ;)

Comment: Well then go on and provide some that show that my answer is wrong. It's not that I wouldn't accept any difference. It is about telling what is wrong and not only about discussing how a professional expert you are. Add some proofs for your statement that this method can't be used for making the cache consistent in specfic situations, or just be silent. Because what you're doing here isn't really helping. And btw: If I were the lead developer of hibernate, I would maybe take care that the people in my forum get help and I'd do something against the spam-bots in there as well.

Comment: Again, I am not worried about you.  You seem willing to accept some random person's internet blog as gospel.  Thats your prerogative.  I am worried about others comeing after and believing what you accuse me of doing (namely claiming something without a proof).  And I choose to help people out on IRC and more recently here; the Hibernate forums is not my choice of forum.  As a person willing to spend my time helping people (on my own time, free of charge) I get to chose where I do that; odd concept huh?

Answer (score 5):

Attached object instances live only within a `Session` in Hibernate. If you terminate your transactions and sessions correctly, the level 1 cache will be purged. What pattern do you use for session management? Session-in-view?

I'm asking this, because your problem seems to me like a Session-termination issue.

EDIT:

I don't see Session.close() or at least Session.disconnect() in your code. As far as I know it's not automatic with unbind().

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it made me re-think about my session-management and definatelly, you're right. Always closing every opened session is so(!) important since it also ensures that you get the newest database changes. Sadly it didn't help me with the final problem, but still, it made me fix a part of it! Thanks a lot!